# Understanding Memory Constraints In R

Tags: r, memory, memory-management

As the title suggests, I am trying to fully understand memory constraints with R because I have a project that is quickly growing in scale, and I am worried that memory constraints will soon become a major issue.

I am aware of `object.size`, and I get the following output when run on the largest item in my environment:

```
> object.size(raw.pbp.data)
457552240 bytes
```

...so the largest item is ~457MB. I have also checked on my macbook pro's memory, in the About This Mac --> Storage, and it shows my Memory as `8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3`, so I assume I have 8 GB to work with.

Obviously the 457MB dataframe is not the only object in my R environment, but I do not want to manually run `object.size` for every single object and add up the bytes to find the total size of memory used. Is there a better way to do this? A function that tells me the memory used in total by all objects in my RStudio Environment would be great. Does such a function exist?

Also, what happens when I get closer to 8GB - is my R script going to stop working? I'm anticipating my data is going to increase by a factor of 5 - 10x in the near future, which will probably bring the total memory used in the environment close-to, or even greater than, 8GB.

Lastly, if hitting 8GB of memory is going to hault my R script from running, what are my options? If I convert my dataframe into a datatable, could that reduce the size of the object overall?

Any help with this is greatly appreciated, thanks!!

**Edit:** saved as a `.rda` file, `raw.pbp.data` is only 32MB, so that makes me optimistic that there is a way to potentially reduce its size when loaded into R.

Comment: I think `pryr::mem_used()` gives the total memory use.

Comment: Another useful link https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/udyq7/ff_or_bigmemory/

Comment: tons of great feedback in this posting, thanks everybody

Comment: Be aware that summing the object.size values and taking the difference from physical ram may not be sufficient. R requires that new objects reside in contiguous memory blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any functions, but this works. You could make a function out of this:

```
env <- eapply(environment(), object.size, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
sizes <- c()
for (i in 1:length(env)) {
  sizes[i] <- env[[i]][1]
}
sum(sizes)
```

Besides the obvious (running this on a server or buying more RAM), I've heard `data.table` is more efficient than `data.frame`. Try using it. The syntax is more concise too! I cannot recommend `data.table` enough.